# DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport will throw groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: groovy

I want to use some methods from DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport, for example "closeQuietly".

Example:

```groovy
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
out.closeQuietly();
```

This will throw an exception:

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.FileOutputStream.closeQuietly() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

When I call it in this way, it will work:

```groovy
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
DefaultGroovyMethods.closeQuietly(out);
```

Why will the methodes from DefaultGroovyMethods not applied?

Comment: For File operations in particular, check (docs)[http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/working-with-io.html] for the `.with` idiom as a recommendation, e.g, `new File('out.txt').withOutputStream{stream -> ...}` which `will handle the exceptions and close the stream in any case`

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `closeQuietly` on an instance of `FileOutputStream` because it's not a method added by Groovy to this class (or any of its parents). In fact, Groovy doesn't add any methods to `FileOutputStream`, but it does add some to it's `OutputStream` parent.

Use the [GDK documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) to see which methods are added by Groovy to JDK classes.

`DefaultGroovyMethods.closeQuietly` is just a regular static method, so you can invoke it.....statically, e.g.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
DefaultGroovyMethods.closeQuietly(out);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought is was added to the Closeable... The Groovy Editor in Eclipse is recommending this call, so I thought it was a good idea to use it

Comment: You can see here that this method is not added to `Closeable` http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/Closeable.html 
Eclipse's support for Groovy is very poor, I would be suspicious of anything it recommends.